# How to download windows sharepoint services site list

Tags: list, development, client-object-model, custom-list

I'm trying to download windows SharePoint services site list using client side object. I'm getting error 500 error site does not exist.How can I download list data from windows SharePoint services

Comment: sharepoint version?how you trying to download it?

Comment: pls, check your ULS logs and post the result

Comment: url is correct ,the same code is working for one url (i.e site collection is in SharePoint farm).This site is windows SharePoint services site.Is this is the problem, I'm new to SharePoint services. Both the sites is same.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are a part of [SPWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_members.aspx) not [SPSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite_members.aspx). Once you have the correct web, it's pretty easy to extract the list from the web.

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(webUrl);
context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
targetWeb = context.Web;
targetList = targetWeb.GetList("http://server/listUrl");
context.Load(targetList);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(var item in targetList.Items)
{
    string title = item.Title;
    var fieldOne = item["myCustomField"]
    var fieldTwo = item["anotherField"]
    // save the list item
}
```

Once you start iterating through the items in the list, you will need to pass in the field (i.e. column) name to get the data out. You can also use the [Fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.fields.aspx) property on the list to figure out what columns are dynamically.

Comment: I'm using the below code, but I'm getting site didn't find.
Is there any problem if site is windows SharePoint service

ClientContext context = new ClientContext(Url);
targetWeb = context.Web;
targetList = targetWeb.GetList("http://server/listUrl");
context.Load(targetList);
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach(var item in targetList.Items)
{
    string title = item.Title;
    var fieldOne = item["myCustomField"]
    var fieldTwo = item["anotherField"]
    // save the list item
}

I'm new to sharePoint,please help.

Comment: You can look at the [TraceCorrelationId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj168853.aspx) property on the context object. From there, you can use the [ULS Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to find the server side trace and filter it down by the correlation id. Can you also post the exact error you are getting in the question?

Comment: error :An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.(This error I'm getting context.ExecuteQuery(); line)